# ¿Tener diferentes aplicaciones y agruparlas eso vendría a ser un micro servicio?

Tags: laravel

Actualmente cuento con 3 aplicaciones independientes de si : Aplicacion de Punto de Venta (Compras y ventas) , Restaurantes  y hoteles cada uno con sus propias bases de datos.

Todas estan hechas con laravel 5.5.

Mi duda es , si yo agrupo esas tres aplicaciones y las interconecto via HTTP para que interactuen estaria construyendo una arquitectura de microservicios.

En todo caso , me podrian poner ejemplos de como podria ser la implementacion  y tal vez interconexion de una arquitectura de micro servicios.

Comment: Más bien eso sería tener servicios, micro servicios es todavía más pequeño, por ejemplo una API que sólo haga cosas de compras y otra que sólo haga cosas de ventas, esos dos microservicios serían para tu App de PV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No creo que sea microservicios. Los microservicios sería como servicios pequeños que hacen una tarea específica y no guardan ningún estado. Aparte de eso, puedes tener múltiples instancias de esos servicios pequeños en diferentes maquinas o nodos y balancearlos.

Ahora, creo que los microservicios irían orientados al negocio, a poder separarlos y agruparlos con un inventario en donde diga que dominios del negocio se ven representados con esos microservicios.

Para tu caso, podrías acercarte o hacer microservicios si desacoplas los servicios de los sistemas y les das responsabilidades detalladas a cada uno. Así, podrías tener esos servicios pequeños en otras maquinas y poder replicarlos y balancearlos. Si recuerdo bien, creo que para que se consideren microservicios, no deberían persistir información o mantener estados.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de un proyecto orientado a microservicios en .Net Core:
[Primeros pasos con Microservicios Github](https://github.com/Joac89/Microservicios)